# Validate Property With Attribute (Alternative to Enterprise Lib Validation Block)

Tags: .net, validation, enterprise-library

Are there any alternative to Enterprise Library Validation Block?  I want to be able to add validation attributes to my properties.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download [Code Contracts](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/) from microsoft research. Note that this feature will be included into forthcoming .net 4.

Answer (score 0):

Could you give an example of what you want to do exactly?